# Which ad network for cross platform web apps

Tags: mobile, ads

It is really unclear what to use when you want to put ads on a cross-platform web application published as is on a website and also on the stores through phonegap.

Admob, Adsense ...?

Moreover, which one has a simple html/js integration system?

For now, I am using inmobi and their js api is very simple and nice, but I have cross domain problems...

Can you help clarify ?

Comment: Sohan from InMobi here. What cross-domain problems have you faced with InMobi though ?

Comment: Hi Sohan, I get plenty of cross domain problems with Chrome like this : ` Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://i.w.inmobi.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://boardlineapp.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. VM373:1`

Comment: I don't think that is an InMobi related problem. I found a similar question on StackOverflow which should help you out. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941139/methods-of-removing-the-youtube-iframe-api-console-error-blocked-a-frame-with

Comment: @Sohan it's the 'same origin' policy of Chrome...so your inMobi js api simply doesn't work with Chrome, is that right ? If yes, it is really annoying !

Comment: Thats not true, Louis. Many people use the InMobi JS Api in Chrome. Also, look at the previously linked question too. Doesn't mean Youtube API doesn't work with Chrome :)

Comment: ok @Sohan, so what is the solution to avoid this in Chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Akshay, JS Dev, InMobi. InMobi is an ad-distributor. The ads/creatives are made by the advertisers. Also, these ads are placed in an iframe so that these ads cannot access the data present in your page, thus providing security. Because some ads try to "burst" out of the iframe, chrome throws the warning. However, these warnings can be safely ignored and will not affect your website's functionality.

That being said, InMobi's javascript is not responsible for these issues, rather the advertiser and InMobi has no control over this. There are some ad networks which require a dummy page to be present on your domain. By using such ad networks, the chrome warnings disappear (because the iframe is on your server and cross domain problems do not occur). However, by doing so, the ad has complete access to your webpage, compromising security.

Comment: Hi Akshay, thanks for this precise answer, I get it now.